# Is there any operator.unpack in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Is there any built-in version for this

```
def unpack(f, a):
    return f(**a) #or ``return f(*a)''
```

Why isn't *unpack* considered to be an operator and located in operator.*?

I'm trying to do something similar to this (but of course want a general solution to the same type of problem):

```
from functools import partial, reduce
from operator import add
data = [{'tag':'p','inner':'Word'},{'tag':'img','inner':'lower'}]
renderer = partial(unpack, "<{tag}>{inner}</{tag}>".format)
print(reduce(add, map(renderer, data)))
```

as **without using lambdas or comprehensions**.

Comment: It took me half a minute to get what this code is supposed to do, and I'm quite familiar with functional programming. A more explicit version may be much cleaner and understandable.

Comment: You might want to look into `itertools.starmap`... but I don't think that will work for dict unpacking.

Comment: you should also strike out the `as clean as possible` part :)

Comment: `**` is in the operator module as `operator.pow()`. In a function call, it expands to a list of keyword arguments, which themselves aren't a kind of object a function could return -- the keyword concept only applies to function call arguments, not function `return` statements.

Comment: really intresting @martineau, but I didn't manage to make it work. Can you show me a code example of the operator.pow being used to unpack into a function?

Comment: I didn't mean you could use it, just pointing out that it's already taken for something else (and secondly that even if it weren't, it's not possible to define a function that could return the kind of values needed anyway). What do you think of my answer below?

Answer (score 4):

That is not the way to go about this. How about

```
print(''.join('<{tag}>{inner}</{tag}>'.format(**d) for d in data))
```

Same behavior in a much more Pythonic style.

Edit: Since you seem opposed to using any of the nice features of Python, how about this:

```
def tag_format(x):
    return '<{tag}>{inner}</{tag}>'.format(tag=x['tag'], inner=x['inner'])
results = []
for d in data:
    results.append(tag_format(d))
print(''.join(results))
```

Comment: not what I'm after, I know this solution to, but I want to avoid using ** explicitly everytime

Comment: What do you have against `**`? Here, since it's only a few, fixed, arguments you could do `.format(tag=d['tag'], inner=d['inner'])` if you really want to avoid `**`.

Comment: the code becomes more readable and you avoid code duplication.

Comment: haha, you funny man @Abe:D I want to get as far away as possible from the second code sample, that is way I'm trying to make a function that can unpack the tuple, this since I'm using .format which tries to print the dict/tuple as is. My goal is to tell the computer what to do not how to do it.

Comment: @SlimJim The first option is most definitely better than anything you seem to consider good. The second would also be decent if Python hadn't much better options for that. They aren't better because they tell the computer how to do what you want but because they make it easier for other *people* to figure out what that is ;-)

Comment: Sorry man but I'm always opting for higher abstraction, I have a mathematical background so to me reduce, map, partial and other such operations really pops out when I look at it. This in contrast to loops and setting variables which really hurts my eyes. Lambdas is okay but I would like to avoid them as well as defining new functions each time that unpacks the variables correctly.

Comment: There is the builtin `apply`, which you would use as `apply('<{tag}>{inner}</{tag}>'.format, (), d)`, but it has been deprecated since 2.3 because `**` is so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an operator that does what you want, but you don't really need it to avoid lambdas or comprehensions:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
data = [{'tag':'p','inner':'Word'},{'tag':'img','inner':'lower'}]
print(reduce(add, map("<{0[tag]}>{0[inner]}</{0[tag]}>".format, data)))
```

Seems like it would be possible to generalize something like this if you wanted.

Comment: Cool didn't know you could do that with a format, but it missed the point, the '...'.format was just an example, I want a more general solution for the actual unpacking. To bad there is no type for _unpacked variables_ in Python. The `def unpack(f,a): return f(**)` will have to do then. Thanks man

Comment: You never said what you have against using `**a`. I would be interested in knowing -- it seems very useful when you need it.